# How can I add a shortcut to the windows games folder using C# or VB.Net?

Tags: .net, shortcut, special-folders

The games folder does not feature in Environment.SpecialFolder collection.

I want to programmatically add a shortcut to that folder.

Comment: P/Invoke the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx), pass `FOLDERID_Games` as the `KNOWNFOLDERID` value. Make sure to write fallback code for operating systems where this function and/or the Games folder do not exist.

Comment: @Joe, Thank you. I did that, but couldn't get the path since by definition, the Games folder is declared as Virtual. How can I add a shorcut to it then?